# Getting 500 error when using Slack's incoming Webhook via a Ruby rest_client

Tags: ruby, rest-client, slack-api

I use the following to post to [Slack's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) [incoming Webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks):

```
slack_incoming_webhook = 'URL....."
payload={
        "text"=> bot_response[:bot_response],
         "channel"=>"@mememem"
    }

jsonresponse = RestClient.post slack_incoming_webhook, payload, :content_type => 'application/json'
```

**I get the following error:**

> RestClient::InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error

The post appears to be posting correctly when I check it on request_bin, so I am unclear how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
require 'json'
payload={   
        "text"=> bot_response[:bot_response],
         "channel"=>"@mememem"
    }.to_json
```

Comment: That's probably it. I did not use that for another API call but in retrospect it probably should be. Thank

Comment: One additional note: Be sure the channel name is correct and contains the # or @. I was getting the bad json error when I was using "channel" instead of "#channel"